# Vue router prop not working after migrating project from vuejs2 to vuejs3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

Why it is not possible to pass router params as prop anymore in vuejs 3? The following code use to work perfectly fine in vuejs 2 but now it doesn't work. I've check the documentation and I am doing exactly as per it and it is still not working. Please bear in mind that I am using vue version 3.3.13 and vue-router version 4.2.5. Here is the link to the demo:

(https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vue-router-forked-5xd2tn?file=%2Fsrc%2Fmain.js%3A18%2C20)

I have 2 pages Home.vue and Detail.vue;

In Home.vue I have a simple router-link

`<router-link :to="{ name: 'detail', params: { id: '123' }}">Go on the page detail</router-link>`

And on the detail page, I am trying to display the id param but it's not working.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">Hello on the Detail page: {{ id }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["id"],
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.id); // id is undefined in console
  },
};
</script>
```

This is the router config:

```
const routes = [
  { path: "/", component: Home },
  {
    path: "/detail/",
    name: "detail",
    component: Detail,
    props: true,
  },
];
```

I also tried the following router config but still didn't work:

```
const routes = [
  { path: "/", component: Home },
  {
    path: "/detail/",
    name: "detail",
    component: Detail,
    props: (route) => ({ id: route.params.id }),
  },
];
```

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Is this your whole code? the anonymous function for props of the routes array has a syntax error. If you want to return an object without a `return` keyword you have to wrap it in brackets like so: `(route) => ({ id: route.params.id })`

Comment: Ah thank you, I didn't notice I made a syntax mistake while typing. Anyway, even though it doesn't solve the prop issue. I've edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

The param isn't actually being passed to the route because it's not defined on the route within your `routes` array.  You need to add `:id` to the path

```js
{
  path: "/detail/:id",
  name: "detail",
  component: Detail,
  props: true,
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, no you don't need to define it in the url. In vuejs v2, we could pass params without defining it in the url. Let's just say, I don't want the id to be shown in the url.

Comment: Not all code can unfortunately be made, or expected to be, backwards compatible.  They fixed it so you can no longer take advantage of this anti-pattern in [vue-router 4.1.4](https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/CHANGELOG.md#414-2022-08-22).  There are multiple alternative strategies in the provided link, e.g. Pinia (or my answer)

Comment: I didn't know that it is now considered as anti-pattern because it was not mentioned in the DOC, Thank you.